# SignalR in ReactJS - work with the same hubConnection within different components

Tags: reactjs, signalr, signalr.client

I'm new to React and just recently started integrating SignalR into a React web-app.

SignalR works fine, but what I initially thought is that I could have some kind of a service/helper class that would instantiate a hub connection so I could use the same one across multiple components, but unfortunately, and as I understand React, you're supposed to handle everything as 'component based' and within the components' states.

- What's the best approach to work with SignalR, without having to create multiple connections to the same hub?

- How to work with a single connection in different components? Are we supposed to create a single connection on the App-component level and pass it to every other component as a prop, or is there a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

I recently created a React plugin for my SignalR library. https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy

I did it as a HOC (Higher-Order Component) https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki/React-Client

For me this is very convenient because then users can unsubscribe automaticly when component is killed.

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    signalR.eventAggregator.unsubscribe(this.myRef.current);
}
```

HOC's are great since you can control the life time

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/blob/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Client.React/signalR.eventAggregator.react.jsx